# How to read a binary file quickly in c#? (ReadOnlySpan vs MemoryStream)

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I'm trying to parse a binary file as fastest as possible. So this is what I first tried to do:

```
using (FileStream filestream = path.OpenRead()) {
   using (var d = new GZipStream(filestream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
      using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) {
         d.CopyTo(m);
         m.Position = 0;

         using (BinaryReaderBigEndian b = new BinaryReaderBigEndian(m)) {
            while (b.BaseStream.Position != b.BaseStream.Length) {
               UInt32 value = b.ReadUInt32();
}  }  }  }  }
```

Where `BinaryReaderBigEndian` class is implemented as it follows:

```
public static class BinaryReaderBigEndian {
   public BinaryReaderBigEndian(Stream stream) : base(stream) { }

   public override UInt32 ReadUInt32() {
      var x = base.ReadBytes(4);
      Array.Reverse(x);
      return BitConverter.ToUInt32(x, 0);
}  }
```

Then, I tried to get a performance improvement using `ReadOnlySpan` instead of `MemoryStream`. So, I tried doing:

```
using (FileStream filestream = path.OpenRead()) {
   using (var d = new GZipStream(filestream, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
      using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) {
         d.CopyTo(m);
         int position = 0;
         ReadOnlySpan<byte> stream = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(m.ToArray());

         while (position != stream.Length) {
            UInt32 value = stream.ReadUInt32(position);
            position += 4;
}  }  }  }
```

Where `BinaryReaderBigEndian` class changed in:

```
public static class BinaryReaderBigEndian {
   public override UInt32 ReadUInt32(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> stream, int start) {
      var data = stream.Slice(start, 4).ToArray();
      Array.Reverse(x);
      return BitConverter.ToUInt32(x, 0);
}  }
```

But, unfortunately, I didn't notice any improvement. So, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is your bottle neck? CPU, Memory, Disk access?

Comment: Nowhere! This is why I'm surprised.

Comment: Why are you copying the entire file in to a memory stream first? That is going to eat up a significant amount of time

Comment: The reasons are because it takes me less overall time for reading from the hdd and because I'm avoiding page faults.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I did some measurement of your code on my computer (*Intel Q9400, 8 GiB RAM, SSD disk, Win10 x64 Home, .NET Framework 4/7/2, tested with 15 MB (when unpacked) file*) with these results:

No-Span version: **520 ms**
Span version: **720 ms**

So `Span` version is actually slower! Why? Because `new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(m.ToArray())` performs additional copy of whole file and also `ReadUInt32()` performs many slicings of the `Span` (slicing is cheap, but not free). Since you performed more work, you can't expect performance to be any better just because you used `Span`.

So can we do better? Yes. It turns out that **the slowest part of your code is actually garbage collection** caused by repeatedly allocating 4-byte `Array`s created by the `.ToArray()` calls in `ReadUInt32()` method. You can avoid it by implementing `ReadUInt32()` yourself. It's pretty easy and also eliminates need for `Span` slicing. You can also replace `new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(m.ToArray())` with `new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(m.GetBuffer()).Slice(0, (int)m.Length);`, which performs cheap slicing instead of copy of whole file. So now code looks like this:

```
public static void Read(FileInfo path)
{
    using (FileStream filestream = path.OpenRead())
    {
        using (var d = new GZipStream(filestream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
            {
                d.CopyTo(m);
                int position = 0;

                ReadOnlySpan<byte> stream = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(m.GetBuffer()).Slice(0, (int)m.Length);

                while (position != stream.Length)
                {
                    UInt32 value = stream.ReadUInt32(position);
                    position += 4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class BinaryReaderBigEndian
{
    public static UInt32 ReadUInt32(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> stream, int start)
    {
        UInt32 res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                res = (res << 8) | (((UInt32)stream[start + i]) & 0xff);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

With these changes I get from **720 ms** down to **165 ms** (4x faster). Sounds great, doesn't it? But we can do even better. We can completely avoid `MemoryStream` copy and inline and further optimize `ReadUInt32()`:

```
public static void Read(FileInfo path)
{
    using (FileStream filestream = path.OpenRead())
    {
        using (var d = new GZipStream(filestream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];

            do
            {
                int bufferDataLength = FillBuffer(d, buffer);

                if (bufferDataLength % 4 != 0)
                    throw new Exception("Stream length not divisible by 4");

                if (bufferDataLength == 0)
                    break;

                for (int i = 0; i < bufferDataLength; i += 4)
                {
                    uint value = unchecked(
                        (((uint)buffer[i]) << 24)
                        | (((uint)buffer[i + 1]) << 16)
                        | (((uint)buffer[i + 2]) << 8)
                        | (((uint)buffer[i + 3]) << 0));
                }

            } while (true);
        }
    }
}

private static int FillBuffer(Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
{
    int read = 0;
    int totalRead = 0;
    do
    {
        read = stream.Read(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length - totalRead);
        totalRead += read;

    } while (read > 0 && totalRead < buffer.Length);

    return totalRead;
}
```

And now it takes less than **90 ms** (8x faster then the original!). And without `Span`! `Span` is great in situations, where it allows perform slicing and avoid array copy, but it won't improve performance just by blindly using it. After all, `Span` is designed to have [performance characteristics on par with `Array`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/docs/specs/span.md), but not better (and only on runtimes that have special support for it, such as `.NET Core 2.1`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tested both your solutions, but I could get only a speed up of about 3x. I'm creating a large buffer that contains all the uncompressed file. The most of time is taken by your `FillBuffer` function. Is there a way to get a better `FillBuffer` and `ReadBytes` (I need a function that can work like stream.readBytes() or span slice) or maybe better library to uncompress GZip files?

Comment: I tested on relatively small file, which was probably cached in RAM by Windows (due to my repeated tests), so reading this file was blazingly fast. If your file is big and not cached, program is likely to spend more time by reading data from disk and thus be slower. You can try open file with one of the `new FileStream()` overloads, that allows to specify advanced options like buffer size, sequential file access, etc. You can also try experimenting with size of my buffer `var buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];` - larger buffer allows less calls to OS...

Comment: ...on the other hand smaller size increases chance that buffer will completly fit into L1/L2 cache. I intentionally tried to avoid `ReadBytes()`, because of problems with slow garbage collection. I also noticed that (for no obvious reason) my program was ~100ms slower when I target .NET Framework 4.7.1 (instead of 4.7.2). I never used any 3rd-party GZip library, so you'll have to ask Google for help :)

Comment: Ok, still thank you for your help. Do you know if exists a way to improve avoiding garbage collection in my first version of the code, the one that uses MemoryStream?

Comment: As long as it calls `base.ReadBytes(4)`, there probably isn't much you can do about it. You coluld try to [postpone GC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.GC.TryStartNoGCRegion);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2), use [GC server background mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#background_server_garbage_collection) ...

Comment: ... or with .NET Core 2.x even [write your own GC](http://tooslowexception.com/zero-garbage-collector-for-net-core-2-1-and-asp-net-core-2-1/) ;-) But still the best way is to avoid allocation completely and work directly with `MemoryStream`'s internal buffer (just like I did in my first example with `new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(m.GetBuffer()).Slice(0, (int)m.Length)`).